New Eclipse J2EE and Open Liberty or IBM Liberty - Previously run install with ears and wars for server view
I used to be able to run open or IBM liberty as a server instance and then add ears or wars to the project if I had multiple.  Now it seems they changed the configuration possibly for both with Eclipse 2024 J2EE web version.
I see that maybe the new open liberty plugin is designed for maven.  We dont use maven for liberty.  Is there another way around this?  Also the IBM liberty plugin is not showing under server either.  The IBM section is not there anymore.
If you see here, I installed all these, none of them worked such that I want to integrate my ear or war code with the server.  I guess I can use manually with a running instance of liberty and just copy the war.



(1) Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers -
2024-03 (4.31.0) include, do not install anything from marketplace (2) Eclipse Menu -> Window -> Preferences -> (Left Side  Tree) Server -> Runtime Environment , (Right Side) Button Add -> (New Server Runtime Environment) -> IBM -> WebSphere Application Server Liberty Extended Tools -> (Install Runtime Environment) -> Enter the destination path: (You must select an empty directory) , (Option Seclect) Download and install new runtime environment from ibm.com: WAS Liberty with Java EE 8 Full Platform.

restart eclipse, Eclipse Menu -> Window -> Preferences -> (Left Side Tree) Server -> Runtime Environment , (Right Side) Button Add -> (New Server Runtime Environment) -> IBM -> Liberty Runtime

Ok I can still but still, will the developer tools show up?
The IBM option is not available that way.

If you're not using Maven or Gradle you might be better off for now skipping the newer "Liberty Tools" and using the "IBM Liberty Developer Tools".   The newer "Liberty Tools" has a more Maven/Gradle centric approach.
See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/comment/8422#comment-8422 too and feel free to chat at https://gitter.im/OpenLiberty/developer-experience

Ok, that is what I was thinking.  I stilled all of them but IBM liberty still didn't show up.  Will check again, maybe that version was not right.
Thanks, that is the  answer if you want to put
